# How can I view the IntelliJ IDEA "Test Runner Tab" when running tests from maven?

Tags: unit-testing, maven, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA when I normally run a unit test I got a dialog that shows me test progress and lets me easily go through the test results. However, I'm using maven for my normal build process and would like to run my unit tests from maven as well. However, when I run my tests from maven instead of with Ideas default "Make" process the "Test Runner Tab" does not appear and I have to manually open the surefire report files in order to find out what went wrong.

So in short "How can I enable the pretty 'Test Runner Tab' for unit test run from a maven build?"

Comment: You can't, run the tests from IDEA.

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer. I was just hoping to keep with the one build process in case Ideas compiler does things significantly differently from how maven would build it.

Comment: @CrazyCoder - Is it possible to do that from the latest Intellij IDEA now ?

Comment: @MasterJoe2 You have to use IntelliJ IDEA test runner for that like in the answer to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently figured out as close as I think I'll be able to get to an answer.  The tests themselves have to be run from [[image]intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea).  But I can still configure **IntelliJ IDEA** to run the build via **maven** first.

[image: Edit Run Debug Configuration]

As you can see in the Red Highlighted Box I've selected a saved maven build configuration for it to run. So as not to duplicate tests, and keep things simple its a simple `mvn package -DskipTests` type build.  I'm still curious if the tests are any different having **IntelliJ IDEA** run them vs the [maven-surefire-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-surefire-plugin) but now I at least know that the build process is the same.

Answer (score 5):

You can run tests using the maven project window in IntelliJ View - Tool Windows - Maven Projects

Then under the project or module you wish to test open the lifecycle goals and click test.

This will run the currently configured test goal. Now the report is logged into the target directory

I use https://github.com/destin/maven-test-support-plugin  to view the test results.

You can access this screen once the plugin is installed from the Project window again right click on the projects root and select "Show Test Results" (should be below the maven icon)

Good luck

Comment: How do I install that plugin given in github ?