# How do I perisist Directory exclusion in IntelliJ idea after a directory has been deleted?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I use Idea for my IDE and I'm using Maven for the actual build process. However, Unit tests by default show up in target/surefire-reports I'm fin with that. However, if I tell maven to exclude the target directory then checking them is quite difficult.  If I don't exclude the target directory and try to exclude the sub directories that actually contain generated code like `target/generated-sources` the next time I do a clean the directory is removed and IDEA forgets about the exclusion.

How can I make those exclusions stick around until the directory is created again?

Comment: Why don't you run your unit tests from intellij?  It already has a good unit test runner.

Comment: I do. I've also figured out how to get it to run maven as the build process before running the tests. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325124/how-can-i-view-the-intellij-idea-test-runner-tab-when-running-tests-from-maven  
but That only works when I explicitly tell it too.  The annoying part is when an a test fails during a normal build.